# although using toList() for-loop still only iterates through index 0 string in the list, why?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to display a Text of the key of a map and a listview builder of the key's corresponding value.

```
Map<String, List<String>> todoDate = {};
```

add key and value using 2 textfields and a button:

```
if (todoDate.containsKey(dateController.text)) {
                            todoDate[dateController.text]
                                ?.add(taskController.text);
                          } else {
                            setState(() {
                              todoDate[dateController.text] =
                                  [taskController.text];
                            });
                          }
```

body:

```
for (var key in todoDate.keys.toList()) {
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                        child: Text(
                          key.toCapitalized(),
                          style: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 26,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: todoDate.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              for (var value in todoDate.values.toList()) {
                                for (var singleValue in value.toList()) {
                                  return TodoCard(data, index, checktodo,
                                      context, todoDate, singleValue, key);
                                }
                              }
                              return const SizedBox();
                            }),
                      )
                    ],
                  );
                }
```

The problem is that only the index 0 of the value is being displayed, and same problem for displaying key.
example: `{'Today':['code','read'], 'Tomorrow':['code,'read']`. Only index 0 of the list value is being displayed and same for the key

Comment: this is because you break your `for` loop by calling `return`

Comment: @pskink, I have 2 for-loops (a single for loop and a nested one), both have return, I remove both return keywords?

Answer (score 0):

you could do this:

```
List<Widget> _list =[];

for (var key in todoDate.keys.toList()) {
                  _list.add(Column(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                        child: Text(
                          key.toCapitalized(),
                          style: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 26,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: todoDate.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              List _listOfTodoCards = [];
                              for (var value in todoDate.values.toList()) {
                                for (var singleValue in value.toList()) {
                                  _listOfTodoCards.add( TodoCard(data, index, checktodo,
                                      context, todoDate, singleValue, key);
                                }
                              }
                              return _listOfTodoCards;
                            }),
                      )
                    ],
                  );
                }
return _list;
```

Comment: Doesn;t work...

Comment: you should return the _list after for loop

Comment: I updated my answer, hop this update resolve your problem